# loop through all sub folder and create one txt file

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch script that loop through all sub folder and then create one text file in all sub folder . The file name of that text file should be the name of sub folder .

Example

folder/folder1/folder1.txt

folder2/folder2/folder2.txt

I've tried this , but the txt files weren't created in the sub folder but in the main folder .

```
set startdir="C:\Users\abc\folder"
FOR /F  %%a in ('dir /AD /B /S "%startdir%" ' ) do (
cd %%a
echo  %%a >%%a.txt
)
```

Where did i do something wrong ? or any idea how can i do this .I'm new for this batch so sorry if I've asked stupid question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
set "startdir=C:\Users\abc\folder"
for /d /r "%startDir%" %%a in (*) do >"%%~fa\%%~nxa.txt" echo(%%~nxa
```

Recursively under the indicated folder (`/r "%startDir%"`) for each directory (`/d`) write to a file with the name of the directory and `.txt` extension (`%%~nxa.txt`) placed inside the full path of the directory (`%%~fa`)

***note*** Read the output of `for /?` for a full list of allowed options

Or, if the `for /f` is required (ex. hidden folders)

```dos
set "startdir=C:\Users\abc\folder"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
    dir /s /b /ad "%startDir%" 2^> nul 
') do >"%%~fa\%%~nxa.txt" echo(%%~nxa
```

**edited** to adapt to comments. If it is necessary to change active directory to the one being processed, then

```dos
set "startdir=C:\Users\abc\folder"
for /d /r "%startDir%" %%a in (*) do (
    rem Change to the folder being processed
    pushd "%%~fa" 

    rem do whatever is needed
    > "%%~nxa.txt" echo echo(%%~nxa
    echo ....
    echo ....

    rem And before the iteration ends, restore 
    rem previous active directory
    popd
)
```

Comment: thank for your answer, it works perfect . I have another question if you don't mind . Can i do a loop through all subfolder, then change the working directory into that subfolder , do something then change to next folder . Like i've tried with cd doesn't work as i expected.

Comment: @darkD, answer updated. You can change the active directory, but you should restore the previous one before each iteration ends.